# How to effiecently union multiple 3d polygones and cast them to another table?

Tags: postgresql, 3d, postgis

I am working with a large amount of CityGML 3d building data (LoD2) and imported the data using the 3D City Database (and its Importer/Exporter tool) (see https://www.3dcitydb.org/3dcitydb/) which creates a new schema in the database and uses java routines to translate the XML-style geodata to PostGIS compatible database input. 
 
The information (spatial and non spatial) for each building is then written to different tables, where *"building"* table holds building meta data such as building function or street name and *"surface_geometry"* table holds solid and 3d surface geometries of all buildings. With columns "id", "parent_id" and "root_id" used as PKs and FKs to ensure the elements of one table can be matched to one or more elements of the other table. 
Since I need 2d building footprints (or bird view polygones) for most of my analyses, I created queries to make surfaces 2d with `st_force2d()` before `st_union()`ing all 2d surface of the same building with `group by` on the available FK.

**Are there any ideas how to improve the following code to effiecntly process a huge dataset?**

The queries are

```
CREATE TABLE citydb.building_geom_tmp AS
SELECT a.*, b.bldg_footprint AS geom
FROM Citydb.building AS a
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *, ST_Force2D(geometry) AS bldg_footprint FROM citydb.surface_geometry
        ) AS b
ON a.lod2_solid_id = b.root_id;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS citydb.building_geom ;
CREATE TABLE citydb.building_geom AS
SELECT a.*, b.geom
FROM citydb.building AS a
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT id, ST_Union(geom) AS geom
        FROM citydb.building_geom_tmp  AS c
        GROUP BY c.id
        ) AS b
ON a.id = b.id;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS citydb.building_geom_tmp
```

I am working on a VM with Win 10 and
`SELECT version()` and `SELECT postgis_full_version()` give

> PostgreSQL 13.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

and

> POSTGIS="3.1.1 3.1.1" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.1"
> PROJ="7.1.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29" LIBXML="2.9.9"
> LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" RASTER

respectively.
The 3dcityDB is 4.1.0 on the virtual machine with postgres/postgis-versions shown above.

Sample CityGML LoD2 data could be downloaded from the German Federal Agency for Cartography and Geodesy ([here](https://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/web_public/gdz/testdaten/LoD2-DE-utms-citygml.zip)).

In addition I asked the 3DCityDB developers for ideas in ther github repo [here](https://github.com/3dcitydb/3dcitydb/issues/73).

Thanks in advance for any ideas and best regards
André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from the developers directly on Github:
https://github.com/3dcitydb/3dcitydb/issues/73

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).